# Login Form thymeleaf (no Spring) does not work

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, servlets, thymeleaf

this is my first question here.
I created a login form that check login username and password from a database.

I don't understand why when i put right username and password ("ok", "ok") and click submit, the page is refreshed, but do nothing. I try to write some sendError message for "debugging" and no one of these is shown.
I hope someone can help me :)
P.S. thymeleaf tags are commented because they do not work and i have to understand why, but it's a secondary problem.

GoToPlaylistPage.java

```
@WebServlet("/GoToPlaylistPage")
public class GoToPlaylistPage extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private TemplateEngine templateEngine;
    private Connection connection = null;


    public GoToPlaylistPage() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        try {
            ServletContext context = getServletContext();
            String driver = context.getInitParameter("dbDriver");
            String url = context.getInitParameter("dbUrl");
            String user = context.getInitParameter("dbUser");
            String password = context.getInitParameter("dbPassword");
            Class.forName(driver);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new UnavailableException("Can't load database driver");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new UnavailableException("Couldn't get db connection");
        }

        ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
        ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver(servletContext);
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        this.templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        this.templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String path = "";       
        if(session.isNew() || session.getAttribute("user")==null) {
            path="LoginPage.html";
            response.sendRedirect(path);
            return;
        }
        else {
            String ctxpath = getServletContext().getContextPath();
            path = ctxpath + "/getPlaylist";
            response.sendRedirect(path);
            return;
        }
        
        
    }


    
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e){
                
            }
        }
    }

}
```

LoginPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Page</title>
<!-- <link th:href="@{/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet"> -->
</head>
<body> 
    <div class="container">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="title"><span>Use this form if you're already registered to musical playlist web application</span></div>
            <form th:action="@{/checkLogin}" method="post">
                <div class="row">
               
                    Username <input type="text" name="username" required autofocus>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    Password <input type="password" name="password" required>
                </div>
                <!-- p th:text=${missing==true} ? 'Both Username and Password required'></p>
                <p th:if="${invalid==true}">Wrong Username or Password</p>-->
                <div class="row button">
                    <input type="submit" value="Login">
                </div>
                <div>If you're not registered, please sign up <a href="RegisterPage.html">here</a></div>
            </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CheckLogin.java

```
/**
 * Servlet implementation class CheckLogin
 */
@WebServlet("/checkLogin")
public class CheckLogin extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private TemplateEngine templateEngine;
    private Connection connection = null;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public CheckLogin() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        try {
            ServletContext context = getServletContext();
            String driver = context.getInitParameter("dbDriver");
            String url = context.getInitParameter("dbUrl");
            String user = context.getInitParameter("dbUser");
            String password = context.getInitParameter("dbPassword");
            Class.forName(driver);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new UnavailableException("Can't load database driver");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new UnavailableException("Couldn't get db connection");
        }

        ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
        ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver(servletContext);
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        this.templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        this.templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    }
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String path="";
        boolean missing=false, invalid=false;
        HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        User user=null;
        UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO(connection);
        ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
        final WebContext ctx = new WebContext(request, response, servletContext, request.getLocale());
        if(username == null || password == null) {
            missing=true;
            ctx.setVariable("missing", missing);
            session.invalidate();
            path="/WEB-INF/LoginPage.html";
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "if user, pass null");
            templateEngine.process(path, ctx, response.getWriter());
        }
        else {
            try {
                user=userDAO.checkCredentials(username, password);
                if(user==null) {
                    invalid=true;
                    session.invalidate();
                    ctx.setVariable("invalid", invalid);
                    path="/WEB-INF/LoginPage.html";
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "if no user");
                    templateEngine.process(path, ctx, response.getWriter());

                }else {
                    session.setAttribute("user", user);
                    String ctxpath = getServletContext().getContextPath();
                    path = ctxpath + "/goToPlaylistPage";
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "indirizzo verso la pagina GoToPlaylist");
                    response.sendRedirect(path);
                    return;
                }
            }catch(SQLException e) {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Database Acess Failed1");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

GetPlaylist.java

```
/**
 * Servlet implementation class GetPlaylist
 */
@WebServlet("/getPlaylist")
public class GetPlaylist extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Connection connection=null;
    private TemplateEngine templateEngine;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public GetPlaylist() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        try {
            ServletContext context = getServletContext();
            String driver = context.getInitParameter("dbDriver");
            String url = context.getInitParameter("dbUrl");
            String user = context.getInitParameter("dbUser");
            String password = context.getInitParameter("dbPassword");
            Class.forName(driver);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new UnavailableException("Can't load database driver");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new UnavailableException("Couldn't get db connection");
        }

        ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
        ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver(servletContext);
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        this.templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        this.templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<Playlist> playlists = null;
        PlaylistDAO pdao = new PlaylistDAO(connection);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String path="/WEB-INF/Home.html";
        ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
        final WebContext ctx = new WebContext(request, response, servletContext, request.getLocale());
        try {
        playlists = pdao.getPlaylists((User)session.getAttribute("user"));
        ctx.setVariable("ownerPlaylists", playlists);
        templateEngine.process(path, ctx, response.getWriter());
        }catch(SQLException e) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Database Acess Failed3");
            return;
        }
        
    }

    

}
```

PlaylistDAO.java

```
public class PlaylistDAO {
    private Connection connection;
    
    public PlaylistDAO() {
        super();
    }
    
    public PlaylistDAO(Connection con) {
        this.connection = con;
    }
    
    public List<Playlist> getPlaylists(User user)throws SQLException{
        List<Playlist> p = new ArrayList<Playlist>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM playlist WHERE Creator = ?";
        ResultSet result = null;
        PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
        
        try {
            pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            pstatement.setString(1, user.getUsername());
            result=pstatement.executeQuery();
            while(result.next()) {
                Playlist pl = new Playlist();
                pl.setId(result.getInt("ID"));
                pl.setOwner(result.getString("Creator"));
                pl.setTitle(result.getString("Title"));
                pl.setDate(result.getString("Date"));
                p.add(pl);
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new SQLException(e);

        } finally {
            try {
                result.close();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                throw new SQLException(e1);
            }
            try {
                pstatement.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                throw new SQLException(e2);
            }
        }       
        return p;
    }
}
```

UserDAO.java

```
public class UserDAO {
    private Connection connection;

    public UserDAO() {
        super();
    }

    public UserDAO(Connection con) {
        this.connection = con;
    }
    
    public User checkCredentials(String u, String p)throws SQLException {
        User user = null;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? and password = ?";
        ResultSet result = null;
        PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
        
        try {
            pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            pstatement.setString(1, u);
            pstatement.setString(2, p);
            result=pstatement.executeQuery();
            while(result.next()) {
                user= new User();
                user.setUsername(result.getString("username"));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new SQLException(e);

        } finally {
            try {
                result.close();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                throw new SQLException(e1);
            }
            try {
                pstatement.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                throw new SQLException(e2);
            }
        }       
        return user;
    }
    
    public boolean existingUsername(String u)throws SQLException {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?";
        ResultSet result = null;
        PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
        
        try {
            pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            pstatement.setString(1, u);
            result=pstatement.executeQuery();
            while(result.next()) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new SQLException(e);

        } finally {
            try {
                result.close();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                throw new SQLException(e1);
            }
            try {
                pstatement.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                throw new SQLException(e2);
            }
        }       
    }
    
    public User registerNewUser(String u, String p) throws SQLException{
        String query = "INSERT INTO user (Username, Password) VALUES ('?','?')";
        int n;
        User user = new User();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
        try {
            pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            pstatement.setString(1, u);
            pstatement.setString(2, p);
            n=pstatement.executeUpdate();
            connection.commit();
            connection.setAutoCommit(true);
            if(n==1) {
                user.setUsername(u);
                return user;
            }
            else return null;
            
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            connection.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new SQLException(e);

        } finally {
            try {
                pstatement.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                throw new SQLException(e2);
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    version="4.0">
    <display-name>TIW_Bom</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>dbUrl</param-name>
        <param-value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tiw_project_playlist?serverTimezone=UTC</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>dbUser</param-name>
        <param-value>root</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>dbPassword</param-name>
        <param-value>rootPassword</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>dbDriver</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>GoToPlaylistPage</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a real debugger in an IDE? It might help you to understand to flow of the programm better

Comment: In eclipse, i can’t debug with tomcat. I can only run my webapp on server. Have you some advice for debugging a web application?